# Python opencv video capture giving abort trap

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv

I recently got a new Mac (macOS 10.14) and am trying to run the video capture method with openCV and python2.7.15.

```
import cv2
cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

And I am getting the following error message:

```
Abort trap: 6
```

I have no idea why this is happening, it worked fine on my old computer, my guess is something with camera permissions maybe? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is a iterm related issue. I solved it by running it in macos default terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same error after update to macOS 10.14(Mojave).

I used otool to debug, got this :
[mac os error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DmeB.png)

These file reported on picture is from :/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework

---

after update iterm to "Build 3.2.4beta1", the "privacy problem" solved

Comment: Hi @chaos, welcome to SO! please note that this does not provide an answer to the question. You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context.

Comment: Ok, then please keep in mind that this is not a forum, it's a question/answer website, where such discussions are generally kept in the comments or avoided. Please consider putting your discussion in a comment and removing this answer.

Comment: yep, it's not an answer, it's more like a discussion. well, My point is: According to "CMIO_Unit_ScopeElement.h:200:SafeGetElement Throwing error", it's likely a permission issue just like Wso said.

Comment: No, don't comment your answer, comment the question and remove your answer.