# opencv cv::VideoCapture indecipherable errors

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, webcam

**OpenCV** version 3.4.3
**Xcode** version 10.1 (10B61)
**macOS** version 10.14.2 (18C54) Mojave

I am using C++ to run an extremely simple program.
This code is used to access the macbook webcam.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture camera(0);
    return 0;
}
```

These are the messages from the Xcode console.
I couldn't find any resources to debug this situation.

```
CMIO_Unit_ScopeElement.h:200:SafeGetElement Throwing err: -67454
CMIOUnitFigBaseObjectImpl.c:246:CMIOUnitCreateFromDescription Invalid paramater
CMIO_Unit_Input_Device.cpp:244:GetPropertyInfo CMIOUInputFromProcs::GetPropertyInfo() failed for id 102, Error: -67456
CMIO_DAL_PlugIn.cpp:269:StreamCopyBufferQueue got an error from the plug-in routine, Error: 1852797029
CMIOHardware.cpp:339:CMIOObjectGetPropertyData the System is exiting
CMIOHardware.cpp:339:CMIOObjectGetPropertyData the System is exiting
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: If you look in the comments of the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684552/python-opencv-video-capture-giving-abort-trap) it might be a permissions issue. Can you "run with administrator" on a mac?

Comment: [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52634009/opencv-python-scripts-mac-aborts) which suggests it could be related to permissions/authorizataion of camera access

Comment: @GPPK I think "run with administrator" is a Windows thing. In mac settings, I went to "Security & Privacy" -> "Camera Access" which had my program's .exe file already having authorized camera access.

Comment: This could potentially be an issue with your installed camera driver, wherein your code is attempting to access it, but your driver is denying that access...try camera(1) to fall back to your default drivers

Comment: @SaranshKejriwal I never tampered or manually updated the camera driver since it is the default one that came with the machine. camera(1) or camera(2) doesn't work.

Comment: I am also seeing similar messages using the AVFoundation and Vision frameworks from swift.